# PHP Get the newest opened application

Tags: php, powershell

Good day!

I am getting all the applications that you can see in the task bar (with the help of powershell) and place all the results in the notepad. This script would run for every minute. I am trying to make a php code on which it would fetch the contents of the notepad and try to get rid of the redundant apps that has been placed on the notepad and would only get the newly opened ones then print it out. For example, I have opened

first minute

1. notepad
2. chrome

next minute

1. notepad
2. chrome
3. firefox -> this would be the only one to be printed out

I only want the newly opened one to be printed out.

What I am trying right now is to run 2 powershell script (one in every minute and one in every 2 minute) so I can have two outputs, get the difference from the array and print it out but it seems like its not a proper way to do it.

Codes I have right now:

```
        <?php

        $filename1 = 'C:\Users\Fluke\Desktop\apps\runningapps1.txt';
        $filename2 = 'C:\Users\Fluke\Desktop\apps\runningapps2.txt';

        if ($file1 = fopen($filename1, "r")) {
            $read1 = fread($file1,filesize($filename1));
            $line1 = explode("\n", $read1);

            $file2 = fopen($filename2, "r");
            $read2 = fread($file2,filesize($filename2));
            $line2 = explode("\n", $read2);

            $result1=array_diff($line1,$line2);
            $result2=array_diff($line2,$line1);

            echo "1";
            print_r($result1);
            $output1 = print_r($result1, true);
            echo "<br>";echo "2";
            $output2 = print_r($result2, true);
            print_r($result2);

            var_dump($line1);
            var_dump($line2);

            }else
                echo "No newly opened apps";     
        }else
         die("Unable to open file!");
    ?>
```

Is there any other way than what I am doing right now? I'm really new to this. Hope you'll understand.

Comment: PHP is probably not the right tool for the job. Are you trying to build a windows app?

Comment: yes. i need those results so I can send it to the server using cURL.  I'm just trying to print it out for now.

Comment: I would use a single script that does this, not two.  I would export the latest Get-Process results to a CSV at the end of the script, and import them at the beginning of the next run.  Then use compare-object and filter on the side indicator.  Then I would send the result directly with Invoke-WebRequest.  No PHP needed